# Most CSS Grid frameworks use pixel as css units, why?

Tags: css, web-development, grid, website-design

I started to develop my own webdesign using an grid framework [960 CSS Framework](http://960.gs/) and also noticed that most of other famous css grid frameworks use 940/960px as maximum page width? Some of them have an online generators where you can calculate and generate the same framework but for different width size.

Can you tell me why they suggest 960 px as default?

And more important: Why everything is measured in pixels rather than pt, cm, % or any other css units?

**Edit:** Isn't it better to use 'in' as css unit and be sure that on every screen (computer, smartphone) it will have the same size?

P.S. Some other grid css frameworks:

- [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/)
- [YUI 2: Grids CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/)
- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Because it fits nicely into a 1024 wide screen resolution and dividable into different divisions quite easily. It creates a fixed width (why you wouldn't want to use percents). The conversion of arbitrary units such as points, centimeters or inches could vary from system to system.

Comment: Why not 'in' unit?

Comment: same reason its inches.

Comment: But it will not vary in real screen size of objects?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If you create a website which is 16 inches wide (width: 16in;) it will be shown on every screen as a 16 inches? Is this right? And is it better?

Comment: no. because say you have a 96 dpi screen and you have a 192dpi screen. it would not line up with your images

Comment: why would anyone want fixed width is beyond me, and why anyone would want fixed width in inches i just cannot comprehend at all.... you want a layout (for example 16 inches wide) to be 16 inches wide even when viewed on a 3 inch wide screen ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415758/why-width-960px

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the 1024 scrollbar issue, 960 is divisible by many factors making it possible to have many different balanced column width configurations.

Comment: Why not 'in' unit?

Comment: An pixel is a pixel, regardless of the size of a user's monitor. A pixel is the smallest unit of displayable information. This is particularly important for images because making them larger degrades image quality.

Comment: Actually, the CSS specifications originally defined the pixel independent of other length units as "The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch)." From CSS 2.1 on, a `px` is an absolute unit like the `in` and `cm` (and in a fixed relation to these, 96 px = 1 in).